# How water and honey behave with increasing pressure?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, thermal-conductivity

Is there any relation between pressure and viscosity of water and honey?  I hardly found the topic. Is it related to the [Laplace law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young%E2%80%93Laplace_equation)?

Comment: What is the *laplas law*?

Comment: pressure is propotional to the surface tension?

Comment: Oh that Laplace law! No, it's not related to surface tension or the Young-Laplace equation.